# How can I write better a function to find coordinates of neighbors out of given coordinates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm programming a checkers game in typescript.
I'd like to explain some important details to understand how the following code works.
In my game coordinates are a string, like "b4".
I want to get the neighbors of a piece coordinates, but only the neighbors that make sense depending on the player and if the piece in these coordinates is a king or not.
For example, if on "b4" it's player one, I want to get only "a5" and "c5" as possible neighbors.

I wrote the following code to find the neighbors of given coordinates:

```
    type CornerType = {
    [key: string]: string | null;
}

const getPieceCornersCoordinates = (coordinates: string, piece: Piece) => {
    const {row, col} = convertStringCoordinatesToNumberCoordinates(coordinates);
    
    const columnLeft  = ((col - 1) >= 0) ? String.fromCharCode((col - 1) + 97) : false;
    const columnRight = col +1 <= 7 ? String.fromCharCode((col + 1) + 97) : false;
    
    const rowUpper = row +1 < 9 ? row +1 : false;
    const rowLower = row -1 > 0 ? row -1 : false;
    
    let corners : CornerType = {};

    if(piece.isKing){
        corners.leftUpper  = columnLeft  !== false && rowUpper !== false ? columnLeft  + rowUpper : null;
        corners.rightUpper = columnRight !== false && rowUpper !== false ? columnRight + rowUpper : null;
        corners.leftLower  = columnLeft  !== false && rowLower !== false ? columnLeft  + rowLower : null;
        corners.rightLower = columnRight !== false && rowLower !== false ? columnRight + rowLower : null;
    } else if(piece.player === "Player One"){
            corners.leftLower  = columnLeft  !== false && rowLower !== false ? columnLeft  + rowLower : null;
            corners.rightLower = columnRight !== false && rowLower !== false ? columnRight + rowLower : null;
    } else {
            corners.leftUpper  = columnLeft  !== false && rowUpper !== false ? columnLeft  + rowUpper : null;
            corners.rightUpper = columnRight !== false && rowUpper !== false ? columnRight + rowUpper : null;
    }

    deleteNullCorners(corners);
    
    return corners;
}

const deleteNullCorners = (corners: CornerType) => {
    for(let key in corners){
        if(corners[key] === null){
            delete corners[key];
        }
    }
}
```

I think this code is not well written, how can I improve it?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Sometimes a little verbosity really helps to make it clear what you are doing (as do an inline comment or two). In any case, I recommend that you post this question to "Code Review" on the Stack Exchange instead of here (hence my close vote)